# Remove Active Directory Role

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have added Active Directory Role to a test server my mistake :(

Dcpromo has not been run, and the server is not a member of a domain.

How do I remove the Active Directory Role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't panic. Just remove the role using Server Manager.

All you actually do by installing the role is install the necessary binaries to enable you to run `dcpromo` and the associated Domain Controller services.

A server isn't a Domain Controller until it is successfully `dcpromo`'d.

Answer (score 3):

Open Server Manager and remove it like any other role.